# How can I put GitHub examples in XML code docs?

Tags: c#, xml, github, documentation

In Visual Studio, when you hover over `System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes` ([see definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributes?view=net-6.0)), it has a link at the bottom "GitHub Examples and Documentation". When you click on that link, it opens these examples directly in Visual Studio.

Does anyone know how this is implemented in the XML Code docs?
Because that feature would be a pretty neat improvement of our code summaries.

Answer (score 2):

Developers can not add to this feature. Microsoft scanned over 100,000 GitHub repositories and looked at popular repositories to get these examples which I read awhile back in [IntelliCode with API usage examples](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/intellicode-api-usage-examples/)